# Javascript regex to extract title and iframe

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

A Google apps script gets HTTP response content text. The excerpt as is below.

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="background-color: rgb(242, 195, 20);"><span style="color: rgb(192, 80, 77);">Disclaimer:</span></span><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Please note,</span><a href="http://www.g00gl3.com"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">http://www.g00gl3.com</span></a><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> or </span><a href="http://www.g00gl3.com"><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">www.G00gl3.com</span></a><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> is only video embedding websites. All of the videos found here come from 3rd party video hosting sites. We do not host any of the videos. Please contact to appropriate video hosting site for any video removal.</span></p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Dailymotion  <br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/foo1234567890bar? syndication=202279" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Alternate Video  <br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=1234567890&amp;autoplay=no" width="720" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

From this excerpt there is a need to extract title (Dailymotion or Alternate Video) and iframe.

Matching only iframe is already done.

```
/<iframe(.*)\/iframe>/g
```

Now the expected is

```
Dailymotion  <br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/foo1234567890bar? syndication=202279" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and

```
Alternate Video  <br><br></span></strong></div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=1234567890&amp;autoplay=no" width="720" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Can anybody help to write regex to fetch only above.

Comment: Maybe you could use a DOM parser instead of a regex.  Regex doesn't handle nested XML well.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for the reply. Need to check if Google Apps Script has a DOM parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should work:

```
/255\);">([a-zA-Z]+\s+.*)<br><br>/g
```

Comment: Thanks @l-lvadim for the reply. This was very close to the expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to search for only those two titles, this will extract all the information you need:

```
[\s\S]*(Dailymotion|Alternate Video)[\s\S]*(<iframe[\s\S]*<\/iframe>)
```

[Here's](https://regex101.com/r/D78zoV/1)  a page where you can see it working:

Comment: Thanks @Kesty for the reply. The assumptions could not be made as were other titles too.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer work but i thinks it's not very restrictive. this regex  `[\s\S]*(Dailymotion|Alternate Video)[\s\S]*(<iframe[\s\S]*<\/iframe>)` work for your exemples but if the HTML code is wrong the regex match (You can test it).

I have make 2 regex more stronger, the inconvenient is that the regex is so long. The first part of my regex is to match this line :

`<div style="text-align: center;"><strong><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Dailymotion  <br><br></span></strong></div>`

Regex :

`^(\<((\D+)( [a-z]*=\"[\S]*|[ ]\.{0,1}[\S]*\")*)\>).*(Dailymotion|Alternate Video).*\<\/\3\>|(\<\D+\/\>)$`

https://regex101.com/r/XthACq/1

The capture group verify if the HTML is "valid". For exemple you can't have  closed by . When the first line of your html match, you can use the second regex to verify the .

`<div style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/foo1234567890bar? syndication=202279" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>`

Is match by this regex :

`^(\<((\D+)( [a-z]*=\"[\S]*|[ ]\.{0,1}[\S]*\")*)\>).*<(iframe)( [a-z]*=\"[\S]*|[ ]\.{0,1}[\S]*\")+\><\/\5>\<\/\3\>|(\<\D+\/\>)$`

https://regex101.com/r/wBBOi5/1

Like the first regex, the HTML code is verify. Now you can extract the title, the link, all attribute by using capture group.

Comment: Thanks @Mattasse for the reply. I may have tweak this regex and attempt once more.

Answer (score 0):

@l-vadim answer was the closest and I'm using it.

```
/255\);">([a-zA-Z]+\s+.*)<br><br>/g
```